# specgram in python error

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to run the `specgram` function in python, but I am getting the error:

> ValueError: The len(window) must be the same as the shape of x for the chosen axis.

When I run the same exact variables in the `spectrogram`, or `specgram` command, in Matlab it works fine. Why is this?

Here is the python code (`x64` is a 38,022 length array, StackOverflow won't allow it to be uploaded and I don't know how else to upload it):

```
from matplotlib import mlab
import numpy as np
nfft = 4096 
fs = 44100 
step = .001
nwind = np.fix (np.multiply([0.002,0.004,0.008,0.016,0.032,0.064],fs))
noverlap = np.round (np.subtract(nwind,(step*fs)) )
han = np.hanning(nwind[5])
han_norm = han * np.sqrt(np.divide(len(han) , np.sum(np.square(han))))
[y64,f64,t64] = mlab.specgram( x64,NFFT=nfft, Fs=fs, window=han_norm, noverlap=noverlap[5],mode='complex')
```

Comment: The error is a bit tricky: if you set `han=np.hanning(len(x64))` you *still* get the same error. `help(mlab.specgram)` will tell you that `*window*: callable or ndarray ---  A function or a vector of length *NFFT*`, so you have to change all the dimensions to fit each other.

Comment: [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html), on the other hand: `If "window" is a vector, then spectrogram divides "x" into sections of the same length as the vector and windows each section using "window".`

Comment: hi, how would i best handle this solution then? should i take the approach that matlab does, by evenly dividing the "x" into sections of the same lenght as the vector and windows each section using "window" ? Does this also mean that x64,NFFT=nfft, Fs=fs, window=han_norm, and noverlap, have to all be the same size ? is there a simpler way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm unfortunately not familiar with these functions, in either of the languages:) From the [help](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram) it seems to me that only `NFFT` and `window` have to have the same size, in contrary to the error message. If I had to guess: you probably have to cut the data using a proper choice of `NFFT`: the help says "*NFFT: integer --- The number of data points used in each block for the FFT.*". It also says about the first return value: "*columns are the periodograms of successive segments*". So it should make sense.

Comment: Hi, Im really having trouble implementing this. What would you recommend I do in this situation? I really need to get this code working in python.

Comment: Well, I can only guess since as I said, I'm unfamiliar with the area. But have you tried setting `NFFT=len(x64)/4)` and a `window` of length `NFFT`?

Comment: hi I did so as you said however, I'm still having issues. btw did you mean for NFFT = len(x64)/4 and window= len(NFFT) ?

Comment: No, I didn't. Looking at your example, window is an *array*. Which happens to be of length `NFFT`, which is a scalar. So you can try calling `np.hanning` in your code with `NFFT` inside it. I'm no sure it'll work, and I don't know if this is what you'll want to achieve, but this is what I meant.

Comment: Hi, so i decided to write the same specgram function in python. Also, would be able to tell me why spicy wavefile.read and audioread function in matlab, both read same shape/size(exact form too, plot looks alike, different scale due to different values) file but with different values?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with both functions. However, `help audioread` in matlab says "*If you do not specify DATATYPE, or dataType is 'double',  then Y is of type double, and matrix elements are normalized values between -1.0 and 1.0.*". I can easily imagine that a similar normalization is missing from `wavefile.read`.

Comment: Yes, [the doc of scipy.io.wavfile.read](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) doesn't mention any normalization.